# WMI method for returning sql server instances returns empty string

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2012, wmi, wmi-query

I'm trying to create a WMI method to return all server instances but the `GetCorrectWmiNameSpace();` returns an empty string. I use sql server 2012, any idea why is it returning an empty string?

```cs
public bool  EnumerateSQLInstances()
{

    string _instanceName = string.Empty;
    string _serviceName = string.Empty;
    string _version = string.Empty;
    string _edition = string.Empty;
    string _correctNamespace = GetCorrectWmiNameSpace();
    if (string.Equals(_correctNamespace, string.Empty))
    {
        return false;
    }

    string query = string.Format("select * from SqlServiceAdvancedProperty where SQLServiceType = 1 and PropertyName = 'instanceID'");
    ManagementObjectSearcher getSqlEngine = new ManagementObjectSearcher(_correctNamespace, query);
    if (getSqlEngine.Get().Count == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    foreach (ManagementObject sqlEngine in getSqlEngine.Get())
    {
        _serviceName = sqlEngine["ServiceName"].ToString();
        _instanceName = GetInstanceNameFromServiceName(_serviceName);
        _version = GetWmiPropertyValueForEngineService(_serviceName, _correctNamespace, "Version");
        _edition = GetWmiPropertyValueForEngineService(_serviceName, _correctNamespace, "SKUNAME");
    }

    txtResponse.Text += _serviceName.ToString() + ", " + _instanceName.ToString() + ", " + _version.ToString() + ", " + _edition.ToString();

    return true;
}

public static string GetCorrectWmiNameSpace()
{
    String wmiNamespaceToUse = "root\\Microsoft\\sqlserver";
    List<string> namespaces = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        // Enumerate all WMI instances of
        // __namespace WMI class.
        ManagementClass nsClass =
            new ManagementClass(
            new ManagementScope(wmiNamespaceToUse),
            new ManagementPath("__namespace"),
            null);
        foreach (ManagementObject ns in
            nsClass.GetInstances())
        {
            namespaces.Add(ns["Name"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception = " + e.Message);
    }
    if (namespaces.Count > 0)
    {
        if (namespaces.Contains("ComputerManagement10"))
        {
            //use katmai+ namespace
            wmiNamespaceToUse = wmiNamespaceToUse + "\\ComputerManagement10";
        }
        else if (namespaces.Contains("ComputerManagement"))
        {
            //use yukon namespace
            wmiNamespaceToUse = wmiNamespaceToUse + "\\ComputerManagement";
        }
        else
        {
            wmiNamespaceToUse = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wmiNamespaceToUse = string.Empty;
    }
    return wmiNamespaceToUse;
}
```

Comment: Show the method code too for `GetCorrectWmiNameSpace();`

Comment: Are you aware of `wbemtest` utility? Open `Windows Run > Type wbemtest`

Comment: I really can't see how your method could return `null`. Are you sure is not returning an empty string?

Comment: This code is meant for 2008 version, probably it is different from 2012.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to modify the method `GetCorrectWmiNameSpace()` to support later versions of SQL Server, [for 2012 and 2014 it will be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179354.aspx):

```
       if (namespaces.Count > 0)
        {
            if (namespaces.Contains("ComputerManagement10"))
            {
                //use katmai+ namespace
                wmiNamespaceToUse = wmiNamespaceToUse + "\\ComputerManagement10";
            }
            else if (namespaces.Contains("ComputerManagement"))
            {
                //use yukon namespace
                wmiNamespaceToUse = wmiNamespaceToUse + "\\ComputerManagement";
            }
            else if (namespaces.Contains("ComputerManagement11"))
            {
                //use 2012 + namespace
                wmiNamespaceToUse = wmiNamespaceToUse + "\\ComputerManagement11";
            }
            else if (namespaces.Contains("ComputerManagement12"))
            {
                //use 2014 + namespace
                wmiNamespaceToUse = wmiNamespaceToUse + "\\ComputerManagement12";
            }
            else
            {
                wmiNamespaceToUse = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Or you can write more flexible code to be prepared for 13, 14 ... etc. versions of SQL Server.

The problem is that you have used [code that is meant for SQL Server 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and older versions. This method `GetCorrectWmiNameSpace()` then returns `string.Empty` even when SQL Server 2012 or 2014 is installed.